# incrementing a form number in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel basec checklist with a serial number field that must correspond to a serialized product. 
I would like to be able to have the number increase by one for each copy printed.
A couple of weeks ago I found a VBA on line that allowed me to do this but didn't save the form before closing it and cannot find it again.
Any suggestions?

Comment: please specify your problem a bit more I would like to help but there are no clues. Did you mean by any chance to simply count the actual printing? Like on printer or did you have in mind putting them in cells. Or both? The increasing serial numbers are not a problem then

Comment: The number in the excel cell needs to increase by one for each copy printed. I can then save the excel report with the last number printed si i'll know at what number to start at for the next batch that need to be printed.

Comment: if it is about printing then I would suggest saving the serial number in worksheet. Store it in a cell. But you would have to give me more info to write you a code. I am still unsure whether you want to print it on paper or do the counting in excel. If you want to print it on paper just use UserForm which adds one to number stored in cell and then saves the new number to the same cell.